# How to get array of json value using Graphql in swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, graphql, apollo

I am using graphql for get the API values using Apollo. I have successfully downloaded schema.json and get the values from grpahql. but i can't get the values array of json values.

This is my sample response:

```
 {
  "data": {
  "team_Dashboard": {
  "activeMission": "Food Mission",
  "currentMissionChallenges": [
   {
    "id": "123",
    "title": "Challenge",
    "estTime": "5",
    "location": "Anywhere",
    "maxPts": "30",
    "status": "Not yet started"
   },
   {
    "id": "1234",
    "title": " II Challenge",
    "estTime": "5",
    "location": "Anywhere",
    "maxPts": "70",
    "status": "Not yet started"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Graphql query:

```
query teamDashboard($teamId: ID!) {
  team_Dashboard(teamId: $teamId) {
   activeMission
   currentMissionChallenges
 }
}
```

Graphql schema response:

```
missionDeadLine: String
currentMissionChallenges: [JSON]
```

When i add the currentMissionChallenges([JSON]) in my Graphql query get error response from the server. but When i remove currentMissionChallenges from Graphql query, get success response and values from the server.

The problem is currentMissionChallenges is [JSON] format. When i change my graphql query [This is graphql Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxXiz.png)

```
 query teamDashboard($teamId: ID!) {
  team_Dashboard(teamId: $teamId) {
   activeMission
   currentMissionChallenges {
        id
        title
        estTime
        location
        maxPts
        status
    }
  }
}
```

Following error display in dashBord.grpahql

```
Field "currentMissionChallenges" must not have a selection since type "[JSON]" has no subfields.
```

How can i get the json array values from graphql. what is problem for getting Json Values? Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

**`The best thing about GraphQL is we can use the query as model`**

Because the response would be as same as the query, so better we can assign the response to a variable of Query type.

Let me explain with an example:-

Suppose if I need to query about my profile data,

**Profile.graphql**

```
query MyProfile{
    player {
        me {
            id
            secret
            name
            email
            state
            country
            timezone
            picture
            pictureType
            audio
            rank
        }
    }
    countries{
        value
        viewValue
    }
}
```

> Once we'll build the app, it'll create MyProfileQuery in API.swift. In viewController we can use the response as below-

```
var myProfileData: MyProfileQuery.Data.Player.Me? // Declaring the valiable of player Type

ApolloClientManager.sharedInstance
                .fetchQuery(MyProfileQuery(), showLoader: true,
                            viewController: self) { (response) in // Fetching response using Apollo Client Manager
                if let allData = response {
                    if let profiledata = allData.player?.me {
                        self.myProfileData = profiledata // Assigning response into the variable declared
                        self.myEdittingProfileData = profiledata
                        self.updateUI()
                    }
                    if let countryData = allData.countries {
                        self.allCountrydata = countryData
                        self.getPickerDataForState(comppletion: {
                            self.openTimeZonePicker(completion: {
                                print("got timeZone Data")
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }

            }
```

> Now we have response into the **myProfileData** variable which we can use
>   as follows -

Now we can access all the values we have mentioned in our query as below

```
print("player id is-          \(myProfileData?.id)")
print("player name is-        \(myProfileData?.name)")
print("player email is-       \(myProfileData?.email)")
print("player state is-       \(myProfileData?.state)")
print("player rank is-        \(myProfileData?.rank)")
print("player pictureType is- \(myProfileData?.pictureType)")

// player id is-          10
// player name is-        jordan
// player email is-       jordan@domain.com
// player state is-       Ohio
// player rank is-        101
// player pictureType is- custome
//
```

Hope this will help you out

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use custom scalar.

```
import Apollo
public typealias JSON = [String: Any]

extension Dictionary: JSONDecodable {
public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws {

    if let array = value as? NSArray {
        self.init()
        if var dict = self as? [String: JSONDecodable & JSONEncodable] {
            dict["data"] = array as! [[String: Any]]
            self = dict as! Dictionary<Key, Value>
            return
        }
    }

    guard let dictionary = value as? Dictionary else {

        throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: Dictionary.self)
    }
    self = dictionary
}
```

}

```
var currentMissionChallanges = [JSON]()
func getTeamDashboard(id:String) {
     let query = TeamDashboardQuery(id:id)
     apollo.fetch(query:query) { [weak self] result, error in 
          if let dashboards = result.data?.team_dashboard {
             if let array = dashboards!["currentMissionChallanges"] as? 
[JSON] {
self?.currentMissionChallanges = array
}
          }
     }
}
```